# RxJava - where in ViewModel I have to write threads for the method?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, rx-java2

I have:
In Dao:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :status_mudak ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5")
    Single<List<Person>> getFivePersonsFrom(String status_mudak);
```

In Repo:

```
public class PersonRepository {
    public Single<List<Person>> getFivePersonsFrom(String status_mudak) {
        return mPersonDao.getFivePersonsFrom(status_mudak);
    }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PersonRepository mRepository;
    //declaring variables
    public PersonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new PersonRepository(application);
        //initializing variables
    }
    //methods
}
```

Where in ViewModel I have to allocate threads, to handover method further to LiveData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PersonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private PersonRepository mRepository;
private MutableLiveData<List<Person>> mPersonList = MutableLiveData<List<Person>>();
//declaring variables
public PersonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = new PersonRepository(application);
    //initializing variables
}

LiveData<List<Person>> getPersonList() {
    return mPersonList;
}

private void extractPersonList() {
    mRepository.getFivePersonsFrom("some_mudatskiy_status")
        .observeOn(/*rxSchedulers.main*/)
        .subscribe(this::updatePersonList);
}

private void updatePersonList(List<Person> personList) {
    mPersonList.postValue(personList);
}
//methods
```

}

Comment: Now I have this error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type .. .It seems that I cannot use MutableLiveData , no?

Comment: You shouldn't return Cursor to UI, you have to extract List<Person> and put it to mPersonList.
Your UI have to observe this LiveData like this:
mPersonViewModel.getPersonList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), this::updatePersonListView);

private void updatePersonListView(List<Person> persons) {
    // update UI
}

Comment: thank you. 1 more question - where should be usages of extractPersonList() method?

Comment: In ViewModel, of course. VM works with business-logic and requesting/receiving data, updates it in MutableLiveData, UI observes changes